# Way of writing media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I see some write responsive like this,

```
@media screen and (min-width:991px) and (max-width:1200px){
    /* styles */
}   

@media screen and (min-width:767px) and (max-width:990px){
    /* styles */
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:766px){
    /* styles */
}
```

the same thing I write like in this way

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    /* styles */
}   

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    /* styles */
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    /* styles */
}
```

like whenever the design breaks I write that size in max-width: rule, and i get a fully responsive design. But which is the correct way doing the method

Comment: It's really much better to do all the stuff that's global to all viewport sizes outside media queries and then after that use min-width and add the floats and such and then you stack your min-widths smallest to largest. And use fluid css. This keeps media queries to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `500px` as an example, in the first way, only the second property (`border`) will apply:

```
/* 500 is not between 767 and 990, so this rule will ignore */
@media screen and (min-width:767px) and (max-width:990px){
    .elem {
        background: red;
    }
}

/* 500 is between 480 and 766, this rull will apply */
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:766px){
    .elem {
        border: 10px solid green;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8bq4m7w/1/).

But in the second way, both of these rules will apply:

```
/* 500 is smaller than 991, this rull will apply */
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
    .elem {
        background: red;
    }

}

/* 500 is smaller than 767, this rull will apply */
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .elem {
        border: 10px solid green;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8bq4m7w/).

Comment: okay, so this method can also be used, right. if I want to to keep a style, dont write that, and if I want to override a style write a new media screen. and is this type of coding affect loading time in mob devices..?

Comment: Both of them are correct, and can be used. It depends on your situation.